# Moving Current objects (For me Folders) to the parent of the directory their in using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, variables, properties, parent-child, pipeline

I am trying to search through folders on a share drive for subfolders with **"*OutPuts"** in the name. These folders *should have folders* in them but *should not have files*:

```
select fullname,@{N='SubDirectories';E={[boolean]($_ |
get-childitem -directory).count}},@{N='SubFiles';E={[boolean]($_ |
get-childitem -file).count}}
```

When these folders are found I want to move any folders from the output folder to the Project folder (Parent of its Parent). Example:

*Starting Condition:* **C:\AllProjects\Projectfolder\outputs\SubProjectFolder**

*Wanted Outcome:* **C:\AllProjects\Projectfolder\SubProjectFolder**

Here's the full Code:

---

code somewhat reformatted for readability ...

```
$folders=Get-ChildItem C:\AllProjects -recurse -Directory |
    where {$_.name -like "*Outputs"} |
    select fullname,
        @{N='SubDirectories';E={[boolean]($_ |
            get-childitem -directory).count}},
        @{N='SubFiles';E={[boolean]($_ |
            get-childitem -file).count}}

$folders

$folders |
    where {$_.subdirectories -eq $true -and $_.subFile -eq $False} |
    foreach {
        get-childitem |
        Move-Item $_ -destination $_.parent.parent}
```

---

When ever I run the code the following message comes up:

```
cmdlet Move-Item at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Path[0]:
```

I'm pretty new to PowerShell so if someone could help break this down for me and tell me what I'm supposed to put here that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

***UPDATE***

*I've tried it with

```
-Path $_, -Path $_.PsPath, -Path $_.FullName.
```

I've even tried Get-Item. With the -Path though I now get a message that's a little different:

```
cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2 Supply values for the following parameters: Process[0]:
```

Comment: the `Move-Item` cmdlet will accept `-Path` via the pipeline `ByPropertyName` or `ByValue`. you are sending it an object that has `.FullName`, `.SubDirectories`, & `.SubFiles` properties ... and those don't match `Path`. i _think_ you will need to add a `-Path $.FullName` to the parameters.

Comment: also, does `.Parent.Parent` work on your `$_`? it looks like you removed those objects when you ran the items thru your `Select-Object` filter.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Apologize, I realize I mistakenly left off the $_ from the `{get-childitem | Move-Item $_ -destination $_.parent.parent}` I've tried it with `-Path $_, -Path $_.PsPath, -Path $_.FullName`. I've even tried `Get-Item`. With the `-Path` though I now get a message that's a little different: `cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 2
Supply values for the following parameters:
Process[0]: `

Comment: please, always put all the info in your question. if you have updated your code at any point, please include it - stripped down to just what is needed to show the problem.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Got you. Made correction earlier. Just added the extra steps I've taken as well.

Comment: i added a section to your question - `code somewhat reformatted for readability ...`. note that the `ForEach-Object` @ line 13 calls `Get-ChildItem` **_and does not tell it what to act on_**. please, feel free to remove my edit if/when you are done with it. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Thank you, whatever needs to be done to help I'm fine with. I'll try to clean up the question and clarify my thoughts better where I can.